# how to dynamically import components with react ? / Dynamic import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, switch-statement, dynamic-import

I have only been programming with react for a short time and I don't know if there is a more efficient way to perform this task.
I have a series of files that correspond to some svg files.
An example would be the following.

```
export default function CheckIcon(props) {
  return (

    <Icon {...props}>
        options={ CheckIcon }
        />
  );
}

CheckIcon.displayName = 'CheckIcon';
```

then I import them into a component that I call Icon.js where I make a switch for each of the cases and return the corresponding component.

```
import React from 'react';
import CloseIcon from './icons/CloseIcon';
import CheckIcon from './icons/CheckIcon';
import SumIcon from './icons/SumIcon';
import SubtractIcon from './icons/SubtractIcon';
import MultiplyIcon from './icons/MultiplyIcon';
import DivideIcon from './icons/DivideIcon';

export default function Icon({ type, ...props }) {
  const getIcon = () => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'close':
        return <CloseIcon {...props} />;
      case 'check':
        return <CheckIcon {...props} />;
      case 'sum':
        return <SumIcon {...props} />;
      case 'subtract':
        return <SubtractIcon {...props} />;
      case 'multiply':
        return <MultiplyIcon {...props} />;
      case 'divide':
        return <DivideIcon {...props} />;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return getIcon();
}
```

and finally I import the Icon.js file into the component where I am going to display my html

```
  <div>

    {() => {
      return (
          <Icon type="close" />
          <Icon type="check" />
          <Icon type="sum" />
          <Icon type="subtract" />
          <Icon type="multiply" />
          <Icon type="divide" />
      );
    }}
  </div>
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to dynamically import into my Icon.js component the different components that correspond to each of the seg?

thank you all for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could alternatively do it by using `type` as the icon name the use `require` to dynamically load your icon as following:

```js
// Icon.js
import React from 'react';

export default function Icon({ type, ...props }) {
  const TheIcon = require(`./icons/${type}`).default;

  return <TheIcon {...props} />
}

// Then use it
import Icon from './Icon';

<Icon type="CloseIcon" />
```

Comment: This is wrong. You cannot compile such as this `require(`./icons/${type}`)` it will not compile since `require` only accept static file in react native.

Comment: This works well with webpack

Comment: Not working for me in react.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

But the **real answer** is that you're probably using a bundler for your code, and how to do Dynamic Imports will depend on what bundler you are using. Some bundlers have different syntax. Webpack [will recognise `import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1).

But the **real real answer** is that if you're using a bundler, don't try to dynamically import code. It's an early optimization that will cause you more problems than it is worth. Let the bundler do its thing. Webpack does [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and as your code base gets larger, it will be easier to just let Webpack apply the optimizations.

See also the [Dynamic Imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) and [Lazy Loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) sections of the Webpack documentation (if you're using Webpack).